# PhpStorm: How can I change text color

Tags: php, colors, themes, phpstorm

I'm new to use PhpStorm and I have installed color scheme that named Earthsong from Daylerees.

I have no idea that how can I change text color from the images. Do you guys have any solution ?

[image]

How can I change that color? It is really awful for me. I tried to change hex color from the `.icls` file but it didn't worked.

**EDIT**: The behaviour can be simulated selecting the theme Darcula and the scheme *Default*

Comment: you can invoke "Find Action" (`ctrl+shift+a`) with a caret on this element and then type Jump to colors and fonts. This should forward you to corresponding setting

Comment: thanks it worked. Oh i wasted of my two days

Answer (score 1):

You can just read their documentation.
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/configuring-colors-and-fonts.html

Go to **Settings** > **Editor** > **Color Scheme** > **Language Defaults**

In there you can just change any color you like.
The one you want to change is probably in **Semantic Highlighting**.

Answer (score 0):

Go to [settings](http://joxi.ru/YmEJwnqCZDR3l2) and change any colors